# Src folder without CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I'm starting with cmake I'm following a tutorial that has as an example the following structure:

```
$ tree -L 2 ExampleProject/
ExampleProject/
|-- build/
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- inc/
|   |-- Formula.h
|-- src/
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- Formula.cpp
|   |-- main.cpp
```

To include the header files that are in the inc folder I just have to `include_directories` inside CMakeLists.txt in the src folder. However, I would not want to put CMakeLists files in the source folder, because I think that in this folder should be only source files. I don't like to mix build files with application source files. So my idea is to use only top level CMakeLists, ie:

```
$ tree -L 2 ExampleProject/
ExampleProject/
|-- build/
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- inc/
|   |-- Formula.h
|-- src/
|   |-- Formula.cpp
|   |-- main.cpp
```

That is, I don't want to treat the src folder as a subdirectory.
It is possible? Is there something like `source_directories`?

Here is how far I managed to get:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(ExampleProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(inc)

set(BINARY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h)

set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

add_executable(${BINARY}_run ${SOURCES})
```

But it would not work because it has to include the .cpp files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add executable from top level CMakelists.txt file. With `add_executable(target src/main.cpp)`. You can try something like this:

```
add_executable(output src/main.cpp)

add_library(formula src/Formula.cpp)
target_include_directories(formula PUBLIC inc)

target_link_libraries(output PUBLIC formula)
```

Comment: In this case, you did something that I don't want to do but I forgot to say, which is to mixing .h and .cpp in the same directory. I want to leave all the .h files in the inc folder and all the .cpp files in the src folder.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer. Hope this solves your problem.